# Docker seems to include OS?

Tags: docker

I'm just starting docker.

According to some articles, the most significant difference of docker from VM is that it doesn't run on an emulated OS but on the host kernel.

However, when I run the nginx image on my Mac:

```
$ docker run -d nginx
a88142a23cb4e1900093ee4a27303f7d80adb0305e4008203829a84ae29ca4f2
$ docker exec -it a88142a23cb4e1900093ee4a27303f7d80adb0305e4008203829a84ae29ca4f2 bash
root@a88142a23cb4:/# cat /etc/*release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
root@a88142a23cb4:/#
```

So for me, it seems like this container actually runs Debian, and nginx on top of it.

Now I'm totally confused. Can somebody explain this output?

Comment: Why downvote? Please tell me the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker use a base image to start which generally a OS image(Not actually OS. It does not have a kernel). It provides a file system and necessary library to run  your application.

For more details, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53049134/7695859